# What do I do when a user posts an answer correcting another one?

Tags: discussion

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36285176/4121347) question, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36285554/4121347) answer was given 2 minutes after [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36285521/4121347) one. Even I answered the question, with a different approach.

The first answer had some errors. And, the second answer, *I* think, is exactly the same as the first one, just correcting the errors. The answerer of the first answer corrected it, and then it became a duplicate of the second answer (although it still has some typo errors).

Are such answers acceptable, which correct some previous answers?

PS: I now see that the OP has accepted the second answer (i.e, the corrected one).

Comment: I honestly don't know if the accepted answer is correct because I can't make any sense of it. *First thing you should consider when using recursion is the exist state; which means when the function will be exists*. What does that mean?

Comment: Aside from alll the answers to be a bit confusing I think it's okay to have multiple answers that are similiar.  You can use the comments to explicitly tell another answerer that their answer is incorrect or needs editing.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Oh yeah. Bad grammar.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi: I feel like he's trying to make a recursion joke and failing miserably (probably owing to an apparent poor command of English as the OP pointed out).

Comment: People posting extremely similar answers within minutes of each other is common enough that this is probably not a big issue. I think the ideal solution would be to correct the existing answer or leave a comment but that doesn't always work out.

Comment: In this *specific* case, since none of the answers explain why the code works, it's not worth sweating over.

Answer (score 1):

This is in part what the voting system is for. In the event that someone had posted an anserwer that contain mistakes or is not detailed you have 3 options:

Write your own. Write an answer and add detail / error free code which was not found in the first answer.

Downvote the question, and make a comment and suggest to the answerer that they edit and improve their answer. Make sure you check back later and up vote /un-downvote it.

Edit the answer yourself. If you see errors or lack of detail....Edit the answer yourself! This way you can improve the answer without adding a new answer for no reason!

Hope this helps!

Comment: _"Downvote the question..."_ Do you mean the answer?